# React native gesture passes through front view to the view behind

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make a react native app in which I have two views. One is above the behind (`absolute`) view.

I am using `onStartShouldSetResponder` to detect click outside the front view and I want to hide the login state.
But the gesture passes through front View to the view behind.
It means the login_component(below) click is also passed to login_container(below) and hides the view.

Here is my code,

```js
 <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
       onResponderRelease={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}
       style={styles.login_container}
          >
    <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => false}
          style={styles.login_component}
    >
      <Text>Join a room</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Here is my styling code,

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  login_component: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
    margin: "auto",
    borderRadius: 15,
  },
 login_container: {
    position: "absolute",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is a preview of what I am doing - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFz1q.png

Any alternate solution is also welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Did you try modifying the zIndex? Might be a simpler solution if it works.

Comment: Ok wow, haven't tried that thank you would you like to add your answer below? It will help others also.

Comment: Sure, elaborated a bit on the answer as well. Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting a high "[zIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)" CSS property for the JSX element that you want to be able to click. A **higher** zIndex will make sure that element is positioned **above** the one with the lower zIndex.

In your case, you want your "login_component" to be on top of "login_container". So your JSX can be modified as follows (not tested):

```
<View style={{...styles.login_container, zIndex: 99}}> // Lower zIndex (Below)
    <View style={{...styles.login_component, zIndex: 999}}> // Higher zIndex (Above)
      <Text>Join a room</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

Usually you wouldn't have to worry about setting zIndex yourself, but I'm guessing the 'position: "absolute"' property has affected the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution it was simple just to use `stopPropagation` on the `login_component`.

Final code,

```js
 <View onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
       onResponderRelease={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}
       style={styles.login_container}
          >
    <View onStartShouldSetResponder={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
          style={styles.login_component}
    >
      <Text>Join a room</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```